# Redux container inside presentation component with API calls

Tags: javascript, optimization, redux

Redux allows using complex container components inside other "dumb"/presentation components. Point is that mostly the simple components are const literal functions, so with stateless mod it will re-render...a lot.

My concern is that it will also call the components it contains on each render, including these containers that can trigger API calling actions eg. inside `componentDidMount` or other life cycle method.

My current solution is a 'cache' inside store, I trigger api method, but inside I check, *should the request be made**/is cache invalidated to continue or break the API call.

Problem is that these components in my opinion should not be tight coupled, so I cannot trigger the load after some other actions inside totally different component, cause that way it won't be independent.

* - due the fact that store in this case is just a simple map, I check whether the data already exists(or timestamp is outdated) or is it just missing.

Just to picture it better:

```
<SimpleView>
  <Container/>
</SimpleView>
```

(...)

```
class Container extends React.Component {
(...)
componentDidMount() {
  apiCallingActionTrigger()
}
```

Comment: Put a layer of logic in front of the api call and check if it meets the requirements to be called, else don't call it? I see no issue with this. Or just promise chain the actions if you know their order.

Comment: Might be worth noting that if <SimpleView> re-renders <Container /> won't re-mount, i.e. componentDidMount won't be called, componentWillUpdate will be called instead.

Comment: Yes I know, as I have written - other lifecycle methods used as hooks. User might get back to the same view but with different product, so the data should call the api.